# Where does Eclipse ADT store the default keystore path?

Tags: android, adt, keystore

I have a slightly embarrassing problem:

I have an Android app on the store for which I'd like to push an update. My problem is that I've changed computers and now I can't find the keystore used to sign the App.

I most certainly have the file (and private key) as I have a full backup, but my problem is that I can't find the file in it (and cannot remember what I've named it in the first place).

What I would like to know is how I can track this file, either through some fulltext search for headers or by checking the (old) eclipse and/or android configuration files for a path to the file (since it Eclipse had already the path to the keystore everytime i built, it must be saved somewhere...)

I'm using Mac OS X (at the time, Snow Leopard)...

Thank you all for you time

EDIT:

I've partially answered my own question: Couldn't find the config file where Eclipse ADT caches the keystore path, but found out the Eclipse ADT on Mac OS X saves keystores by default in Eclipse.app/Contents/Mac OS (yes, inside the .app package) ... probably a oversight regarding "current directory", but silly nonetheless...

Comment: Could you create a new one and possibly examine it with a hex editor for some Keystore signature?

Comment: Already tried, but the only common identifiable data i could find is the key name and a couple of bytes unsuitable for a mega search :(

Comment: Worse, I just created a new keystore just to see where Eclipse would store the path and still can't find it in the project/workspace metadata :( ... I'm trying it with grep but still no luck... maybe it stores it in some other global place ?

Answer (score 2):

its may in

```
C:\Users\nainit\.android
```